# Open a input text if checkbox is checked (JQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to make a input that just open if checkbox is checked.

```
<script>
if ($('#flexCheckDefault').is(':checked')) {
    $('#test').prop('disabled')
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="flexCheckDefault">
<input type="text" id="test" disabled>
```

I've try this but not got success. Help-me pls!

Comment: you can set a value for disabled property, see here https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Why don't you use a css-only solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#flexCheckDefault').change(function() {
  $('#test').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

Problem with your code is that you don't do anything when the checkbox changes so you need to use `.change()` event.

Also in `.prop('disabled')` you should tell, if it should be disabled or not. like `$('#test').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))`

**Demo**

```js
$('#flexCheckDefault').change(function() {
  $('#test').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="flexCheckDefault">
<input type="text" id="test" disabled>
```

Comment: I still don't get it... why is it working for you ?
This is my code:

<input type="checkbox" id="flexCheckDefault">
<input type="text" id="test" disabled>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    $('#flexCheckDefault').change(function() {
        $('#test').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
    });
</script>

Comment: @AlisonJuliano when do you load the scripts?

Comment: what do you mean with "when" ? I load this script like I paste here in the comments.

Comment: @AlisonJuliano Some people load script in header others just before the end tag of body. Also do you get any errors in console?

Comment: all script is in body tag and no errors appears '-'

Comment: I executed the code in https://jsfiddle.net/ but still didn't work and idk why

Comment: You have to link the correct fiddle, else i cant see it

Comment: @AlisonJuliano In your fiddle you are missing `.` in `$('flexCheckDefault')` and in `$('test')` should be `$('.test')`

Comment: @AlisonJuliano Also you haven't included jquery in the fiddle. Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/pu1zw8eq/